# Where is Itemid used to flag active menu item in Joomla 2.5.6?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Can anyone please help me with the process flow through which the Joomla `Itemid` parameter ends up being the highlighted menu item?

I have embedded a 3rd party application in Joomla and by temporarily changing the php environment within the application.

I am able to get joomla html and insert the 3rd party html by replacing a token.

Simplified Code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = '';
}
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/joomla/index.php?view=mycom&option=com_mycom&Itemid=103';
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/joomla/index.php';
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = 'view=mycom&option=com_mycom&Itemid=103';

ob_start();
require_once '/joomla/index.php';
$joomlaHTML = ob_get_clean();
echo str_replace($replacementToken, $thirdPartyHTML, $joomlaHTML);
```

In v1.5.x, the menu item with ID 103 is properly highlighted but in v2.5.6, it isn't and the `Home` item is always highlighted. I think it used to be highlighted correctly in v1.6.x and earlier versions of 2.5.x as well but not sure.

I wanted to find how the process flows (where this is set) so I can see what tweaks I need to make.

**DELETED WRONG INFO**

Comment: Highlighting a menu item is depends on the type of module means it depends on the code written in module for example in default beez20 template ,a menu item is highlighted using a CSS class named 'current' and "active" and that code is written in modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php.

Comment: Just looked and that is dependent on whether the item = `$active_id`. I am looking for the process flow to the setting of $active_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the breadcrumb part, but I managed to get it working by editing my component's controller.php to read:

```
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// force highlight the external url menu item
$Itemid = JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
$menu->setActive($Itemid);

// force fix the breadcrumb
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');    
$pathway =& $app->getPathway();
$bcrumbs = &JPathway::getInstance('site');

// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

/**
 * MyCom Component Controller
 */
class MyComController extends JController
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks **Dayo**! you saved my day with this:

```
// force highlight the external url menu item
$Itemid = JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
$menu->setActive($Itemid);
```

Answer (score -1):

Look in the following File

Check the

/modules/mod_menu/mod_menu.php

File and you will see two functions has been called "getActive" and "getDefault" 
Which can be find in following file

/libraries/joomla/application/menu.php

I think it can be customized easily now

Comment: Thanks for that. It will be helpful but I was hoping to be able to follow the process through from how the Itemid param is set to be the active menu item. The functions are how the active item is retrieved AFTER it has already been set while I want to follow the `setting` process so to speak.

Comment: setActive() methid is there in /libraries/joomla/application/menu.php you can customize it call it whenever you want but currently in the module it is not called that is why menu item is not highlighting even if it is open you need to call $menu->setActive($id) before calling $menu->getActive() and $id in setActive Method can be get using $id=JRequest::getVar('itemid');

Comment: I see. I suppose the follow on question would be where to put the code to set it in this way in the component. One issue against this approach is that when I call `http://host.com/joomla/index.php?view=mycom&option=com_mycom&Itemid=103` directly, I get the menu item correctly highlighted. It just doesn't work when I try to trick it by changing the environment. This is why I want to follow the process flow for the request. I can use your bypass/hack if all fails. Thanks for staying on this.